# Firebase query for sorting 'posts' by timestamp 'created'

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Currently, I have the following data:

[image]

I'm trying to sort each post from the by newly created 'posts', and include a way to get the newly created posts in a 'page' like format. So for example I can have each page show 2 posts in order by create time. Page 1 would show 'Example post 3' and 'Example post 2'. Page 2 would show 'Example post 3'.

By firebase ref looks like this:

```
new Firebase(config.fb + '/content/posts').orderByChild('created').limitToLast(3)
```

Which I was doing for a test. This oddly gave me the three posts in the order of '... 1', '... 2', '... 3'. I then tried using limitToFirst instead and it gave me the same results. After all of that, I tried multiple combinations of .startAt .endAt sometimes ending in showing no posts, others giving the same order as always.

td;dr / question: How can I sort my 'posts' in a way that lets me grab the posts in order by the created time (timestamp) greatest from least (newest to oldest) and then use a startAt and endAt to be able to grab the 1st newest to the 5th newest post or really anything I want.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: In addition to that: make sure that you include the code that shows the behavior you have problems with. The code you now show does not retrieve the children yet, so can't be the cause of your problem. Simplest is to also show an `on()` handler and `console.log()` the snapshots in a way that highlights your problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior described with the code included. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).